# A quiz question in complex analysis about non- constant holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

This question was asked in my complex analysis quiz and I was unable to solve it. I will ask about only options I was not able to contradict

> Question: Let f be a non-constant holomorphic function in the unit disc {|z|<1} such that f(0)=1.
> Then it is necessary that :

(i) There are infinitely many points z in the unit disc such that |f(z)|=1 .

(ii)There are atmost finitely  many points z in the unit disc such that |f(z)|=1 .

If points in (i) had a limit point then I could have used identity principle to contradict it, but I can't now and i am not able to think about any other result which can be used , so kindly help .

Thanks!!

Comment: See [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1209039/nonconstant-holomorphic-function-f-in-unit-disk-such-that-f0-1?rq=1) or [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/629129/f-be-a-nonconstant-holomorphic-in-unit-disk-such-that-f0-1-then-it-is-nec?noredirect=1&lq=1) or [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/657380/application-of-maximum-modulus-principle?rq=1) or [4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/933989/a-problem-on-holomorphic-functions-in-open-unit-disk?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Hint: any open neighborhood of one contains infinitely many points of modulus $1$